# How to send events to Firebase Analytics from .net App?

Tags: c#, firebase, .net-6.0, analytics

I'm trying to send events to Firebase Analytics from an .net 6 web app.
But I don't know how do that, I don't know if maybe exists any library for use it, or may be an API for send http request.

I'm building a class for use it, but definitely I don't found concrete information about what type of element or configuration to use.

I generate a file .json with OAuth 2.0 but I don't know if I need it.

```
public class MyFirebaseAnalytics : IMyFirebaseAnalytics
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public MyFirebaseAnalytics(string pathJsonOAuth) {
        // Inicializar Firebase con las credenciales
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/your-project-id/events/");

    }
    public async Task<dynamic> SendEventAsync(string eventName, object eventSend)
    {
        try
        {
            var eventData = new
            {
                name = eventName,
                eventParams = eventSend
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eventData);
            var content = new StringContent(json, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("", content);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // El evento se envió correctamente.
            }
            else
            {
                // Manejar el error si la solicitud no se completó con éxito.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```